# How to connect a signal to a slot in a different thread

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, pyqt5, signals-slots

I am using Python 3.6 and PyQt5. I have a gui drawn in a `MainWindow` class which includes a `QComboBox`. I want to send the `currentTextChanged`signal to a slot in a different thread. I am relatively new to signals and slots. How would I go about doing this? Would prefer a written example of a class `Ui_MainWindow(object):` sending the signal to class `Threadclass2(QtCore.QThread):`
Here is a shortened version of my code and what I want:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import threading
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
        def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
            self.keyworddict = {}
            self.count = {}
            MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
            MainWindow.resize(698, 581)
            MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(698, 581))
            MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(698, 581))
            palette = QtGui.QPalette()
            brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(154, 161, 161))
            brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
            palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
            brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(206, 206, 206))
            brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
            palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
            brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(214, 214, 214))
            brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
            palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
            brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(154, 161, 161))
            brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
            palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
            brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(206, 206, 206))
            brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
            palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
            brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(214, 214, 214))
            brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
            palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
            brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(154, 161, 161))
            brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
            palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
            brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(214, 214, 214))
            brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
            palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
            brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(214, 214, 214))
            brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
            palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
            MainWindow.setPalette(palette)
            self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
            self.centralWidget.setObjectName("centralWidget")
            self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralWidget)
            self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 60, 371, 31))
            font = QtGui.QFont()
            font.setFamily("Yu Gothic")
            font.setPointSize(16)
            self.comboBox.setFont(font)
            self.comboBox.setAcceptDrops(False)
            self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
            self.comboBox.addItem("")
            self.comboBox.addItem("")
            MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
            self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)

        def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
            _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
            MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
            self.comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "Jackets"))
            self.comboBox.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "Shirts"))
class Threadclass2(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(Threadclass2, self).__init__(parent)

    def run(self):
        print("awd")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Before this a button will start the thread whilst the gui is still being drawn by the mainwidnow class

Comment: To a certain extent, this may depend on how the multithreaded part of your code is structured. So you should probably include some example code from your application.

Comment: What is the difference between this question and your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46382780/how-to-pass-a-qtwidget-current-text-into-a-qthread?

Comment: I took your advice and asked a more precise question. You did not reply too my previous question comment. I do not know how to connect a signal to a thread slot.

Comment: As said ekhumuro, the solution depends on the implementation of your thread.

Comment: @Kermit You do not have to create a new question, just edit and specify your question in your previous question

Comment: @eyllanesc New to it all so thanks for the advice. The code is too long to show in this question however it consists of one class which holds all the QWidgets and draws the gui and another Threadclass that does a specific list of functions. One of these functions requires the current text of a combobox drawn in the gui created in the main class. That is what my code consists of. I need the combobox signal to be sent to the threadclass somehow.

Comment: @Kermit I think you are able to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), ie a minimal code that can reprodur the thread with a widget that has a combobox, if you do we will help you.

Comment: @eyllanesc I have attempted to add sample code of what I want (take note of in the threadclass where I have written combobox current value. This is where I want the value of the combobox to be sent. Cheers

Comment: @Kermit When I run your code it shows me a window without any widget, please test it, correct it and edit your question.

Comment: @eyllanesc fixed please check thank you.

Comment: try with the following code: https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/b43b4a843fa73854ba9a8911f79f449f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@eyllanesc Solution worked. Adding this class is the key. Cheers

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
    self.setupUi(self)

    self.thread = Threadclass2(self)
    self.comboBox.currentTextChanged.connect(self.thread.setText)
    self.thread.start()
```

Comment: By not showing your code you have lost a lot of time, if you showed it you could help in an instant. :P